# Why does bind allow TTL to be set record by records if different TTLs are not allowed within the same record set

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, bind, nameserver

Why does bind allow TTL to be set record by records if different TTLs are not allowed within the same record set?

If i set the zone ttl using:

`$TTL 39600`

And then set a record TTL using:

```
@        300     IN      A       1.1.1.1
```

I get the warning in my logs:

```
TTL set to prior TTL (300)
```

This is because I have "Different TTLs for records within the same record set, this is not allowed"

If this is not allowed, whats the point of being able to set TTL record by record?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file format is specified in [RFC1034](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt) and parts of [RFC1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt).  It is very old (1987), and not specifically defined for BIND or in light of current features.  There is no great wisdom to be had here; it's like that by convention.

The format is also designed to be used for things like caches, I believe, though in practice this usage must be terribly rare.  In a record cache, TTLs differ often and the cache contains records from many different domains.

Answer (score 4):

BIND allows you to set explicit TTLs for individual records that differ from the zone default TTL, but you cannot set different TTLs for records of the same type with the same name.

You can do this:

```
$TTL 39600
@        300     IN      A       192.0.2.100
```

You cannot do this:

```
$TTL 39600
@        300     IN      A       192.0.2.100
@                IN      A       192.0.2.101
```

Why? Because this would cause some records to time out from cache, leaving others behind, giving your users an incorrect answer to their DNS queries. For example, when you have two records of the same type with the same name, BIND will answer in a round-robin fashion, balancing the load between the two IP addresses. In the above example, 203.0.113.100 would time out after 5 minutes, leaving the other cached for 11 hours. The resolver would not re-query for the record with the shorter TTL because, as far as it knows, it has the answer for that A record query.

Here's a TXT record example:

```
$TTL 39600
@                IN      TXT     "My Google verification code"
@        300     IN      TXT     "My SPF record"
@        300     IN      TXT     "My DKIM record"
@        300     IN      TXT     "My DMARC record"
```

If the above example were allowed, a resolver would cache all 3 TXT records after a query, but my SPF, DKIM, and DMARC records would disappear after 5 minutes. Any mail server using this resolver would not be able to see these records and I would likely have problems with mail delivery.

Comment: This is explained in fact in section §5.2 of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2181 ; from deprecated as explained in this RFC the practice became completely forbidden once DNSSEC arrives, because `RRSIG` records are computed per recordset, and the signature is based, among other things, on *the* TTL of the recordset, so each record inside the recordset have to have the same TTL

Comment: Adding to what Patrick said, it's actually the TTL from the RRSIG's "original TTL" field that is used in the validation process, specifically as the TTL may have been decremented. I think the actual issue in this regard is that you want to ensure that the whole RRset expires at the same time, which is important to get correct behavior already without DNSSEC, but getting a partial RRset would result in outright validation failure in the DNSSEC case. But the single "original TTL" also implies that it must have been the same across all records

Comment: But then why do so many vendors allow this behavior with their DNS editors and what does that actually do when others are resolving? It simply is a fact that even big providers like namecheap allow you to set different TTLs for otherwise identical TXT records.